# JS terminology: saying "a value is an instance of a class"

Tags: javascript

Given that JavaScript uses prototype inheritance and doesn’t really have classes in the traditional OO sense of the word, it would seem that saying

“`x` is an instance of the `ReferenceError` class”

is technically incorrect.  Is there a more terminologically kosher way of expressing that concept?  (Namely, the fact that `x.constructor === ReferenceError`?)

Comment: IMO, using class-like terminology for class-like objects is perfectly reasonable, and has the advantage that others might understand what the heck you're talking about.

Comment: Notable here is the fact that there exist numerous ways to "instantiate" a "class" in JS. `x.constructor === ReferenceError` only holds true for a limited set of those ways. Any exact syntax is only going to hold true for some JS instance/class-esque relationships.

Comment: Why not just "`x` is an instance of `ReferenceError`"? *ReferenceError* is a constructor, you don't have to call it a *class* just because that fits some other idiom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the context of your question -- it's very possible the framework you're using has implemented a class based object system using javascript In this case, the terminology is correct.

If that's not the case, it would be more accurate to say

> x is a `ReferenceError` object
>
> x's type is ReferenceError
>
> x's object type is ReferenceError
>
> x is an object whose type is ReferenceError
>
> x's object type has `ReferenceError` in its prototype chain